# How to hide app chooser window?

Tags: android, sms

I am using smsManager for sending sms using default application in background but every time my app gets open it shows me app chooser i dont want to show this to user

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Comment: try this, http://androiddhina.blogspot.in/2015/12/how-to-send-sms-in-android-without-user-interaction.html

Comment: Pramod I tried this but didnt work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my build problem actually i rebuild the project and the problem get solved. :)